# How to loop through a list based on a condition?

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, traceback

Here is my hypothetical situation:
There is a list of people waiting outside of the club. The bouncer only allows people with ids 18 or older in the club. If they are younger than 18 they are denied admission. Suppose you know the ages of people in line that want to enter they are 18, 27, 16, 17. I created a code to try to run through it, but just cannot get it to work. It works for testing all the items 0 to 99, but I only want it to test items in the list. Can someone help me?

```
ages_of_people_waiting_outside_club = [18,27,16,17]
ages_of_people_waiting_outside_club = range(0,100)
for ids in range(0,100):
    if ids >= 18:
        print("you may enter")
    else:
        print("sorry, you can not come in")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, I would recommend using a foreach loop then nest in an if and else statement. The foreach loop will go through the whole list, then you can basically add in the if and else statements you showed above. Here would be an example using PHP:

```
    foreach($age_of_people_waiting as $age) {
    if($age >= 18){
     print("you may enter");
    }else{
    print("sorry, you can not come in");
    }
 }
```

What this is doing is the array that contains the ages, in this case, $age_of_people_waiting, is being converted to an individual value for each section in the array, that value will be passed as $age. The if statement will then check if that particular $age value that it is on is 18 or over. If it is, it prints "you may enter" if not, it prints "sorry, you can not come in." I'm not sure what coding language you are using, but foreach loops are pretty common and exist in multiple languages, so it's your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
ages_of_people_waiting_outside_club = [18,27,16,17]
#ages_of_people_waiting_outside_club = range(0,100)
for ids in ages_of_people_waiting_outside_club:
    if ids >= 18:
        print("you may enter")
    else:
        print("sorry, you can not come in")
```